# Event loop or CPU, which one block this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

*example:*

```
exports.products = (req, res) => {

  let el = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < 100000000000000; i++) {
    el += i;
  }
  console.log(el);

  ...
  ...
  ...

  res.redirect('/');
};
```

If I add a loop like this between my code, which one will be block (Event loop or CPU) ?

When I run this my page stays on load for a long time to process code.

At the same time, the process list looks like:

[image]

The page stays clogged until this process is finished.

edit:
*When I do operations that do not run the same function from a separate browser, the page remains collapsed.*

Now is this collapsing due to event loop blocking? Or is it because my processor doesn't have the power to spare for it?

Comment: My favorite activity is to come back after a while and see the stupidity of my old  questions. I cannot even delete them because doing so makes SO angry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is a single threaded language. Any synchronous action is run on that thread via [Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). The loop process is running on that thread. So, when the loop is still ongoing JS is using the whole thread and after it finishes, CPU usage should come down.

Your CPU is fine but your code is blocking the main thread.

You can watch this amazing [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0) describing how Event Loop works in JavaScript

Comment: Thank you for sharing the video with me.

Comment: @shaban my pleasure :)